# How do I load an external jar file in a Applet?

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am working on a project in C# but in order for me to progress I need to get my jar file to run.
[This is the jar file](http://oldschool1.runescape.com/gamepack_8614663.jar)

The jar file is a game called Runescape and if I were to double click that jar file it won't do much so I was looking at this example

```
Applet applet = (Applet)classLoader.loadClass("client").newInstance();
applet.setStub(stub);
applet.setSize(new Dimension(763, 504));
applet.init();
applet.start();
i.add(applet);
i.pack();
i.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
label.setVisible(false);
```

Which by the looks of it takes the jar file and runs it in a Applet to give the user a visual representation of the game.
And thought it could be of help.

Now since I am a C# developer with minor Java experience I find it hard to know where to start, I have IntelliJ installed and ready to create a project but what do I need to do in order to get that jar file to run in a Applet so I can later on compile that project and use it a "client" for the game?

Answer (score 0):

Running an applet from an Application is actually not that easy (and not partucally recommended).
I wrote a litte test for your jar file and run into an issue which I belive is that I am missing a proper `AppletStub`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

class appletrunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception //This is not proper Exception handling!
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        File jar = new File("gamepack_8614663.jar");
        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {jar.toURI().toURL()}, appletrunner.class.getClassLoader());
        Class<?> client = classLoader.loadClass("client");
        Applet applet = (Applet)client.newInstance();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                applet.stop();
                applet.destroy();
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        applet.init(); // Exception here
        applet.start();
    }
}
```

This Fails on `applet.init()` with a cryptic Exception (caused by the obfuscator used by runescape jar). But I think with a proper [AppletStub](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletStub.html) which itself requires a [AppletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html) it could work.

You could try implementing a class for these interfaces and add them to the applet with `addStub()`. Hope this is somewhat helpfull.